# how to remove notice error from this code without using @-operator?

Tags: php

I want to remove the notice error? how can i remove it without using the `@`-operator?

```
if($result->CreateResult->RateAccessorials->RateAccessorialItem!=null
```

Error:

```
Error:Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$RateAccessorialItem in /some/path/SaiaSecure.php on line 333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php Checking value is set or not.Use isset function in php

Answer (score 5):

PHP's `isset` construct does exactly this.

```
if(isset($result->CreateResult->RateAccessorials->RateAccessorialItem)){
  // ...
}
```

The above code presumes two conditions for correct operation:

- That `$result->CreateResult->RateAccessorials` is always set
- That `$result->CreateResult->RateAccessorials` is always an object

Edit: I've answered for the sake of question. As a StackOverflow user, it is your duty to select an answer and mark it as such.